# why to make new instance of http for Socket.io when we already have express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, socket.io

I am new to SocketIO, I have referred many blogs and documentation for socket and everywhere we first need to create an HTTP server and then attach the socket to it like this -

```
var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(httpServer);
```

What does the second line mean? why are we creating one extra HTTP server while express(web framework) is already defined?
Because I never created a new HTTP instance for my RESTful application, I simply listened to express instance like this -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(8000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you want socket.io to run on the same port as your web server, then you use the same server instance.  If you want socket.io to run on a different port, then you create a new server instance on that port just for socket.io to use.

Socket.io works just fine using the same port and server instance as Express so unless you have a specific reason to run it on a different port, this is the usual way one would configure it.

Some code examples for socket.io show it in isolation by itself and thus they have to create an http server for it to use.

When using Express, you can get the server instance like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8000);
const io = socketio(server);
```